# Validate decimal number in (known) national format

Tags: php, validation

PHP has many built-in functions to validate numbers but they all expect input in *computer* format: `1234.56`. I need to validate stuff like `1,234.56` (English) or `1.234,56` (Spanish), together with some typical attributes (accepted range, max number of decimals, etc.).

I started writing my own function but I soon got lost. It's easy to *read* the user input into a float variable but I want to be able to detect numbers with invalid formats like `1,23456.7` or `1..25`.

Do you have any recommendation on the subject?

(Decimal and thousand characters are known beforehand and it's okay to hard-code digit groups as three, there's no need to cover [Indian number format](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=10226).)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [`NumberFormatter::parse`](http://php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.parse.php). You can parse numbers in a lot of locales with it. The whole intl extension is useful, even though it is not quite "there" yet.

Comment: Unfortunately, works only in PHP 5.3+, but nice solutions anyways, didn't know about it.

Answer (score 1):

I found an interesting function in a comment in the php manual : https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php#92885
Have a look.

Comment: Although not applied directly to my problem, it's a witty approach. Too bad I got scared of setlocale() after suffering from some bugs in the Windows implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions to validate numbers:

```
$ds = '.'; // Decimal separator
$ts = ','; // Thousand separator

$isValidFloat = preg_match(
    '/^

         # Integer part, one of the two allowed formats:
         # 1) with thousand separator, grouped by 3 digits
         # 2) without thousand separator
         (\d{1,3}(' . preg_quote($ts) . '\d{3})* | \d+)

         # Optional decimal part
         (' . preg_quote($ds) . '\d+)?

    $/x', $string);
```

And convert it to a float like this:

```
$float = (float) strtr($string, array($ts => '', $ds => '.'));
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the given solutions, I'd recommend the [PEAR Validation package](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.validate.validate.number.php) for validating numbers.

Here's an example from their site:

```
<?php
require_once 'Validate.php';

$number = '-8,1';
if (Validate::number($number,
    array('decimal' => '.,', 'min' => -9, 'max' => -7 ))) {
    echo 'Valid';
} else {
    echo 'Invalid';
}
```

If you want to be stricter on the format then you could parse it as a float (which you have done), and then use [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) to output the float into the formats you accept, and try to match the original format against any of the ones you have generated.

Comment: I'll have a look at it.
(It's better not to be so strict: for me, `1000.5` is as valid as `1,000.50`.)

Answer (score -1):

You perform all your calculations and for the result variable, you could use the built-in function **[`number_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)** to format it as per your requirements.

Comment: I don't want to convert from float to string. I want to validate whether a string contains a valid number in national format. `12.345` is a valid number but I can't store it in a DECIMAL(4,2) column. `1000` is a valid number but not a valid discount.