# PHP "is_numeric" accepts "E" as a number

Tags: php, string, numbers, isnumeric

I noticed PHP `is_numeric()` accepts "E" as a number.
I have a string: "`88205052E00`" and I want the result to be: **NOT numeric**.

Here is the code which I tested.

```
<?php

$notnumber = '88205052E00';

if(is_numeric($notnumber)) {
    echo $notnumber . ' is a number';
} else {
    echo $notnumber . ' is NOT a number';
}

?>
```

The Code above gives result:

```
88205052E00 is a number
```

How can I get the result to be: **88205052E00 is NOT a number**?

Comment: `E` is used in scientific notation, so yes, it is considered a valid number.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php

Comment: You might want to look into a regex that checks for non `0-9` characters. And handles decimals `.` if you need them.

Comment: It is a number as long as PHP is concerned ([demo](https://3v4l.org/Jk9Lk)).

Comment: Do you expect negative number or decimals?

Comment: Your request is impossible because `88205052E00` **is** a number. It is `88205052*10^0` which is exactly `88205052`.

Comment: @nerdlyist No, I want only to check for digits, negative or decimals are not expected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I will keep the answer incase it helps but as pointed out there are shortcomings with `ctype_digit` in that it does not like `-` or `.`.

More likely then you want to use ctype_digit which checks if all of the characters in the provided string, text, are numerical.

Where as is_numeric — Finds whether a variable is a number or a numeric string

```
<?php

$s = "88205052E00";

if(ctype_digit($s)){
    echo "Yes";
} else {
    echo "No";
}
```

returns no.

Comment: It is good if you want `3948394873281738173172493274871218201832081239183` to return true and false for `-1`.

Comment: I knew there was a reason I did not use this before. Working on a tweak

Comment: Since I need to check for digits only (I dont need ` - ` or ` . `), this answer solves my problem. Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 2):

`E` is valid because of floating point numbers (http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php).

If you don't want to allow `E` for whatever reason, you could check for it independently:

```
if (strpos(strtolower($notnumber), 'e') === false && is_numeric($notnumber))
```

This makes sure that there isn't an E and that it is also numeric.

Comment: Should be `===`, not `!==`

Answer (score 2):

Just use a regular expression:

```
<?php
if (preg_match("/^\-?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+\z/", $notnumber)) {
    echo "$notnumber is numeric\n";
} else {
    echo "$notnumber is not numeric\n";
}
```

Results:

```
   1234 is numeric
1234E56 is not numeric
  -1234 is numeric
  .1234 is numeric
 -.1234 is numeric
 -12.34 is numeric
```

Comment: Using `trim()` means that `\t\t12345\n\t\t\n` (several whitespace characters on either side) is numeric.

Comment: Yes, I'd assume the use of trim on the original variable. Probably best not to assume though.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to ensure that the string is a valid integer you could use [`filter_var`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php):

```
$tests = ['1', '1.1', '1e0', '0x1'];
foreach($tests as $str) {
    $int = filter_var($str, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
    if ($int === false) {
        echo $str . ' is not an integer' . PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo $str . ' is an integer' . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Result:

```
1 is an integer
1.1 is not an integer
1e0 is not an integer
0x1 is not an integer
```

Comment: If you just want to check if the variable is an integer, couldn't you just use [`is_int`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php)?

Comment: No. `is_int('1234')` returns false.

Comment: ah, my mistake. I could have sworn there was a built-in for this.

Comment: I guess that's what filter_var is for.

Comment: @KodosJohnson There is [`ctype_digit()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/fr/function.ctype-digit.php), though (and the very interesting first comment on the documentation page).

Comment: All functions (including the above) have gotchas. `ctype_digit('239284923942734924729749327')` is true but obviously it is too big for integer.

Answer (score 0):

Let's check [the definition](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php):

> Finds whether the given variable is numeric. Numeric strings consist
>   of optional sign, any number of digits, optional decimal part and
>   optional exponential part. Thus `+0123.45e6` is a valid numeric value.
>   Hexadecimal (e.g. `0xf4c3b00c`) and binary (e.g. `0b10100111001`) notation
>   is not allowed.

The relationship with [floating point literals](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) is clear but, how does it all relate to [integer literals](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php)?

- Octal notation is [considered numeric](https://3v4l.org/VqXiQ).
- Hexadecimal notation [stopped being considered in PHP/7.0](https://3v4l.org/WPJLQ).
- Binary notation [has never been](https://3v4l.org/sRBe5).
- Integer overflow is [not a direct concern](https://3v4l.org/MTDYH) but will lead to precision loss.

The manual doesn't state explicitly what the use cases are but in general it's more a helper tool (to ensure that you can feed stringified data to functions that expect numeric values) than a proper form validator. If input is collected in an environment where `88205052E00` is not expected then it might be a good idea to expect (and generate) localised data and implement a [locale-aware solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942666/validate-decimal-number-in-known-national-format).